# How does a browser request from CNAME?

Tags: http, host, request

Let me put it this way:

1.cname.com has a record of X.X.X.X

www.domain.com has a record of 1.cname.com

When a user request www.domain.com from within his/her browser,his/her browser will send an http request.My question is what is the host name THE http request contains.Is it 1.cname.com or www.domain.com?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hostname inside the HTTP request (in the `Host` header) will be the hostname in the URL, `www.domain.com` in your example.

> The Host request-header field specifies the Internet host and port number of the resource being requested, as obtained from the *original URI given by the user* or referring resource[.] - [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

Comment: More exact: The host name is the one typed into the browser, the DNS resolution is irrelevant at this point. The user types"www.domain.com" then this is what is in the request.

Comment: I sniffed a few packets and found out the host name in the request actually IS the one I typed into the browser.